# need help determining the general formatting of text in a text file

Tags: python, string, format

This question is related to HECRAS if anyone has experience, but in general it's just a question about writing text files to a very particular format to be read by the HECRAS software.

Basically I'm reading some files and altering some numbers, then writing it back out but I can't seem to match the initial format perfectly.

Here is what the original file looks like:

```
Type RM Length L Ch R = 1 ,229.41  ,21276,21276,21276
Node Last Edited Time=Oct-17-2019 15:52:28
#Sta/Elev= 452 
       0  20.097  67.042   9.137   67.43   9.139  68.208   9.073  68.598   9.129
  68.986   9.086  70.538   9.071  70.926   9.042  71.984   9.046   72.48   9.025
  73.646   9.056  74.368   9.034  75.586   9.042   76.55   9.017  77.138   9.047
  78.304   8.989   79.47   9.025   80.19   9.001   81.41   9.003  81.974   8.978
   83.83   9.005  85.284   9.079  85.682   9.068   86.97   9.118  88.012   9.223
   88.79   9.239   89.65   9.316  90.342   9.324  91.134   9.475  91.966   9.525
  92.282   9.589  93.346   9.546  94.222   9.557  94.922   9.594   95.71   9.591
  96.546    9.64  97.286   9.574   98.87   9.688  99.258   9.673  99.642   9.712
#Mann= 3 , 0 , 0 
       0     .09       0   246.4    .028       0   286.4     .09       0
Bank Sta=246.4,286.4
XS Rating Curve= 0 ,0
XS HTab Starting El and Incr=1.708,0.1, 500 
XS HTab Horizontal Distribution= 5 , 5 , 5 
Exp/Cntr=0.3,0.1
```

I'm interested in the Sta/Elev data...it look's like some right justified tab/space? delimited format in station/elevation pairs of 5 per line..maybe 16 chars per pair??

I've tried a bunch of different things, my current code is:

```
with open('C:/Users/deden/Desktop/t/test.g01','w') as out:
    out.write(txt[:idx[0][0]])
    out.write(txt[idx[0][0]:idx[0][0]+bounds[0]])
    out.write('#'+raw_SE.split('\n')[0]+'\n')
    i = 0 
    while i <= len(new_SE):
        out.write('\t'.join(new_SE[i:i+10])+'\n')
        i+=10
    out.write(txt[idx[0][0]+bounds[1]:idx[1][0]])
```

it's a little hacky atm, still trying to work it out, the important part is just:

```
while i <= len(new_SE):
    out.write('\t'.join(new_SE[i:i+10])+'\n')
    i+=10
```

new_SE is just a list of station/elevation:

```
['0', '30.097', '67.042', '19.137', '67.43', '19.139', '68.208', '19.073', '68.598', '19.128999999999998' ...]
```

I also tried playing around with justified side with something like:

```
'%8s  %8s' % (tmp[0], tmp[1])
```

to basically have 8 spaces between the text but right justify them

honestly struggling...if anyone can recreate the original text in between #Sta/Elev= 452 and #Mann I would be eternally grateful, here is the full list if someone wants to give it a go:

```
new_SE = ['0', '30.097', '67.042', '19.137', '67.43', '19.139', '68.208', '19.073', '68.598', '19.128999999999998', '68.986', '19.086', '70.538', '19.070999999999998', '70.926', '19.042', '71.984', '19.046', '72.48', '19.025', '73.646', '19.055999999999997', '74.368', '19.034', '75.586', '19.042', '76.55', '19.017', '77.138', '19.047', '78.304', '18.989', '79.47', '19.025', '80.19', '19.000999999999998', '81.41', '19.003', '81.974', '18.978', '83.83', '19.005000000000003', '85.284', '19.079', '85.682', '19.067999999999998', '86.97', '19.118000000000002', '88.012', '19.223', '88.79', '19.239', '89.65', '19.316000000000003', '90.342', '19.323999999999998', '91.134', '19.475', '91.966', '19.525', '92.282', '19.589', '93.346', '19.546', '94.222', '19.557000000000002', '94.922', '19.594', '95.71', '19.591', '96.546', '19.64', '97.286', '19.573999999999998', '98.87', '19.688000000000002', '99.258', '19.673000000000002', '99.642', '19.712']
```

Answer (score 0):

not really sure if I understood correctly - please consider having a look at

```
# with open('C:/Users/deden/Desktop/t/test.g01','w') as out:
    for i in range(0, len(new_SE), 10):
        row = [f'{float(v):8.3f}' for v in new_SE[i:i+10]]
        out.write(''.join(r) + '\n')

#    0.000  30.097  67.042  19.137  67.430  19.139  68.208  19.073  68.598  19.129
#   68.986  19.086  70.538  19.071  70.926  19.042  71.984  19.046  72.480  19.025
#   73.646  19.056  74.368  19.034  75.586  19.042  76.550  19.017  77.138  19.047
#   78.304  18.989  79.470  19.025  80.190  19.001  81.410  19.003  81.974  18.978
#   83.830  19.005  85.284  19.079  85.682  19.068  86.970  19.118  88.012  19.223
#   88.790  19.239  89.650  19.316  90.342  19.324  91.134  19.475  91.966  19.525
#   92.282  19.589  93.346  19.546  94.222  19.557  94.922  19.594  95.710  19.591
#   96.546  19.640  97.286  19.574  98.870  19.688  99.258  19.673  99.642  19.712
```